# C# Process Dispose throwing Standard Error not been redirected

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable

I am crating a Process object to run a process with a ProcessStartInfo with the correct properties set. This was working until I thought about disposing my Process object. Initially I wrapped it around a using block and that failed after which I explicitly call Close and Dispose in the Exited Event Handler.

The code looks like follows:

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("program.exe", argument)
{
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};
var proc = new Process { StartInfo = processInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true };
proc.Exited += EventHandler;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();

private static void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var p = sender as Process;
    if (p == null)
        return;
    var stdErr = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stdErr))
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Log:({0}) {1} ", p.ExitCode, stdErr));
    p.Close();
    p.Dispose();
}
```

When I add the p.Close() and p.Dispose() I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : StandardError has not been redirected.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardError()
```

StackTrace as follows:

```
Unhandled exception in remote appdomain: System.InvalidOperationException: StandardError has not been redirected.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardError()
   at namespace.EventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\BuildAgent\work\70df16b46ad15c54\Source\Blah.cs:line 318
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.OnExited()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.RaiseOnExited()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.CompletionCallback(Object context, Boolean wasSignaled)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.WaitOrTimerCallback_Context(Object state, Boolean timedOut)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.WaitOrTimerCallback_Context_f(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Object state, Boolean timedOut)
```

Even the following code throws the same exception:

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("program.exe", argument)
{
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};
using(var proc = new Process { StartInfo = processInfo, EnableRaisingEvents =true })
{
    proc.Exited += EventHandler;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}

private static void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var p = sender as Process;
    if (p == null)
        return;
    var stdErr = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stdErr))
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Log:({0}) {1} ", p.ExitCode, stdErr));

}
```

Comment: That code works for me. Are you sure you're not accessing `proc.StandardError` after the `proc.WaitForExit()` call? And is that really the full stack trace you get with the exception?

Comment: There I have updated the question with the stacktrace. I am not sure when to call the proc.WaitForExit() though its not in my handler code..

Comment: Hmm... the stacktrace looks rather convoluted. Are you executing the code using some test runner? Anyway, shouldn't matter. There must be something wrong in parts of your code, that you don't show. Can you post a compilable example, or at least show more context for the part where you start the process?

Comment: Yes it run using a test runner..that shuldnt matter. The process code is executed as part of an executable and it has the event handler bound.. just think of it as part of the Main() function of a Console program

Comment: Sorry, personally I cannot reproduce it and it doesn't make too much sense either: `StandardError` raises the exception you see if the internal member is set to `null` which only happens in `Close` or `Dispose`. The `Exited` event handler is called from inside `WaitForExit`, so in either case happens before `Close` or `Dispose` is called.